# Queries about Optical Remote sensing images

Tags: remote-sensing

I am new in Remote sensing and studying about Optical Remote sensing images.

I found a [research article](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ohfr1my67xpg4i7/paper1.pdf?dl=0), "Learning Rotation-Invariant Convolutional Neural Networks for Object Detection in VHR Optical Remote Sensing Images", that is recognizing the objects in optical remote sensing images. They have used NWPU VHR-10 data set and its color images.

Therefore I started to check about the Optical Remote sensing images and I found this [link](http://www.crisp.nus.edu.sg/~research/tutorial/optical.htm). But in that link they didn't say anything about the color images or they have some different name (Multispectral imaging system, Panchromatic imaging system, and Superspectral Imaging Systems).

The color images used in this paper are Multispectral imaging system OR Panchromatic imaging system OR Superspectral Imaging Systems?
**Sample image:**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  Could you rephrase you question please. It doesn't appear that you're asking anything.

Comment: I agree with @Knightshound - even though you have two question marks you seemed to have placed them at the end of two statements.  From the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: @PolyGeo Can you please remove the hold as i have cleared the question

Comment: @Knightshound please check now

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer because your question only provides a link to the publications's title and abstract.

Comment: @Aaron Now edited the link. Now you can check the full paper.
Also, I have added the sample image from that dataset

Comment: Hi, this is too late to answer this. According to the description of the NWPU VHR-10 dataset, it consists of 800 images. Some of them are typical RGB images while others are pansharpened images. Pansharpening is a fusion technique which is used to generate a product which contains more information than the input products. Check Landsat pansharpening for example which exploits the large spectral resolution of some bands and the large spatial resolution of the panchromatic band.